# CSS Can you set global values

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Within a wordpress site where you sometimes have many css files in multiple locations for theme, 3rd party plugins and such, is it possible (and how) to set global attributes that you know you want sitewide that override all instances?

For example, say I know I want 'border-radius: 0px;' sitewide on all buttons, form fields etc etc

Rather than go on a search and destroy mission sitewide, i'd like to take care of this in one swipe.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Your best bet is to start learning some Sass. It is very easy to pick up and makes management of your CSS a lot easier.

Comment: No, your best best is to start learning some CSS.

Comment: lambo is right, you should [learn SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide). You can set variables for everything (colors, fonts...) and use them in all your SASS files. torazaburo is right too, if you want to override a rule _without using !important trick_, you have to consider [what CSS means](http://www.w3.org/Style/LieBos2e/enter/).

Comment: Thanks - Funny I use CSS every day - But I've never taken the time to properly learn - I know I have wide gaps in my css knowledge.  Will at least check out what SASS is though ...

Answer (score 1):

Although usually frowned on, in your case

```
button { border-radius: 0 !important; }
```

will do the trick.

Comment: why is it frowned upon?

Comment: Because it's a blunt knife. Normally, one would want to structure CSS so that rules worked correctly without having to force them. However, in your case, with unknown numbers of pre-existing rules from various packages, it is a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can write specificity css, which is apply more priority style to elements. In given example second have priority then first one. more details https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

For eg :

```
form input {
  border:1px solid red;
}

#main-content form input{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Right, but how can he know how much specificity to build into a selector in order to make sure it takes precedence over all the other rules in the site?

Comment: seems hard to believe there isn't a straightforward way to specify I want to x to be y in all cases and override anything other.

Answer (score 0):

**Using PHP:**

Assuming that you already are using `PHP` in `Wordpress`, you could manage your variables in a php file.

Instead of linking to a css file, simply use a `style.php`.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.php' />
```

Then on top of your `style.php`, set the content type back to `css`.

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>
```

Now you can define the global variables in your `style.php` as such.

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

   $brandColor = "#990000";
   $linkColor = "#555555";
   $borderRadius = "0";
?>
```

Then while styling your elements, you could do something like below:

```
a {
  color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
  border-radius: <?php echo $borderRadius; ?>
}
```

**Using Css Pre-processors:**

Of course, using [css pre-processors](http://sass-lang.com/) often is a great idea and will take you long way in organising your css files and variables. Pre-prosessors these days not only support variables but even complex `functions`, `mixins`, `loops`, etc. My preferred pre-processor is [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), however feel free to check [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or others.

Comment: I think you're confusing global variables, which is what you are showing, with global rules, which is what the OP seems to want. He wants to write CSS rules which override everything else.

Comment: Hmm. didn't think about that. May be he is. However I will leave the answer here so someday someone else might benefit.